# How to change the verify email message of laravel fortify

Tags: laravel, fortify

Hello I have just started in Laravel and to manage authentication I use the fortify package, my concern is that I cannot configure the default fortify emails for example: **The Verification Mail that the user receives at registration**

I managed the authentication and I would like to personalize the email myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is mentioned in Laravel documentation:

> To get started, pass a closure to the `toMailUsing` method provided by
> the `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail` notification. The
> closure will receive the notifiable model instance that is receiving
> the notification as well as the signed email verification URL that the
> user must visit to verify their email address. The closure should
> return an instance of `Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage`.
>
> Typically, you should call the `toMailUsing` method from the boot
> method of your application's `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider`
> class.

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
 
/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 */
public function boot(): void
{
    // ...
 
    VerifyEmail::toMailUsing(function (object $notifiable, string $url) {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Verify Email Address')
            ->line('Click the button below to verify your email address.')
            ->action('Verify Email Address', $url);
    });
}
```

You can find the full documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/verification#customization)